# Foundation for Apps and ng-token-auth integration

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I have a "Foundation for Apps" application which I would like to extend with authorization.

On the server side there is a Rails application running with the "devise_token_auth" gem. I managed to integrate the "ng-token-auth" module for Angular into the Foundation application, but when I log in there is nothing rendered inside the `ui-view` container.

Here are the files:

user.html

```
---
name: user
url: /user
abstract: true
template: '<ui-view/>'
resolve: function() {function ($auth) { return $auth.validateUser(); }};
---
```

dashboard.html

```
---
name: user.dashboard
url: /dashboard
---

<div class="grid-container">
  <h2>Welcome {{user.email}}</h2>
</div>
```

sign-in.html

```
---
name: sign-in
url: /sign-in
---

<form ng-submit="submitLogin(loginForm)" role="form" ng-init="loginForm = {}">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="loginForm.email" required="required" class="form-control"/>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" ng-model="loginForm.password" required="required" class="form-control"/>
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Sign in</button>
</form>
```

part of app.js

```
angular.module('myApp').run(['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
  $rootScope.$on('auth:login-success', function() {
  $location.path('/user/dashboard');
  });
}]);
```

I hope that someone has a hint for me. What am I missing?

Comment: I feel like there's a lot missing here. "When I log in" implies some login UI that redirects to a concrete state. I'm guessing there's an `otherwise` in there that is supposed to set the active state to `user.dashboard` on successful login? Or is that redirect defined somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the 'resolve' functionality is not yet integrated in the current version (1.1) of foundation for apps.

https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/387

The workaround is to disable foundation.dynamic_routing described here
https://github.com/zurb/foundation-apps/issues/501#issuecomment-76715381

The current downfall with this workaround is that you cannot extend the 'DefaultController' anymore.